# Binding functions to environment to access stored variables, what are the downsides?

Tags: r, rlang

**Problem:**
I need a function which takes only one argument, but needs access to some other variables. I don't want to store these in the `.GlobalEnv`.

**Current Solution:**
Use a function which takes all needed arguments, that create another function which adapt the environment.

**Example:**

```
library(rlang)
foo <- function(a, b){
  bar <- function(c){
    out <- a + b + c
    out
  }
  set_env(bar, get_env())
  bar
}
bar <- foo(1, 2)
bar(3)
```

I strongly believe that this approach have downsides, but I can't put my finger on what these downsides might be. I would be happy if you could help me.

Comment: Your example doesn't really require setting the environment at all, so perhaps you could be a bit clearer about why you need to do this? See: foo1 <- function(a, b) {function(c) {a + b + c}};bar1 <- foo(1, 2);bar1(3)

Comment: Now that it's simplified to this little example I see that it's just nonsense. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: Is there a way that you can rephrase the example to show what you're really trying to do? I'm interested to find out why you've found it necessary. It's a useful philosophical discussion about changing environments like that, and it's a shame to have missed the opportunity.

Comment: My current problem is actually solved, but I'm still interested to hear some opinions about the broader concept of changing the environment of a function (for example to the environment of the caller or some package). Should I edit this one or ask another question?

Comment: Since you accepted an answer to this question, I'd ask another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with this. You don't need rlang either:

```
foo <- function(a, b)
{
    function(c) a + b + c
}

bar <- foo(1, 2)
bar(3)
```

The returned value of `foo` will be another function, whose environment is the one in which it was defined. That happens to be `foo`'s environment.

The only time this might be an issue is if there are other objects in `foo` that interfere with how things should work. To guard against this, you can explicitly create a new environment that is distinct from `foo`'s environment:

```
foo <- function(a, b)
{
    bar <- function(c) a + b + c
    environment(bar) <- new.env(parent=globalenv())
    bar
}
```

but this should rarely, if ever, be necessary.